# Optimize under multiple constraints

Tags: r, optimization

I would like to use some R function in order to optimize a given function under multiple constraints.

```
    # P, z assumed to be arrays of length m^2 
    # (P is actually a m x m matrix but it seems that only vectors are accepted within the optimizer)
    # t1, t2 are constants

    eval_f <- function(P,z,t1,t2){ 
        tmp_sum <- 0
        m <- length(z)
           for(i in 1:m){
              tmp_sum <- tmp_sum + P[i]*(abs(t2*z[m-i+1] - t1*z[i])^3)
           }
      eval_f <- tmp_sum 
   }

   # Let's further assume the following constraints
   # Convert P into a matrix, row sums of P shall sum up to 1 (probabilities), 
   # i.e. the result f_constr_1 should be equal to a zero vector
   # of length m

   f_constr_1 <- function(P){
      len <- sqrt(length(P))
      P <- matrix(P,len,len)
      f_constr_1 <- rowSums(P) - rep(1,ncol(P))
   }

   # The second constraint forces the values of P to be between 0 and 1
   lb <- rep(0,m*m)
   ub <- rep(1,m*m)
```

This is what I got so far. Now I am struggling with the following.

What optimizer could solve this problem? I first started with the following:

```
m <- 4
P <- rep(0.25,m*m)
z <- rep(c(-1.15,-0.32,0.32,1.15),m)

nloptr(P,eval_f,lb=lb,ub=ub,z=z,t1=0.25,t2=0.5,opts=list("algorithm" = "NLOPT_GN_DIRECT"))
```

From a technical point of view this works... but now I want to implement the constraint and suddenly I get the following error message.

```
nloptr(P,eval_f,f_constr_1,lb=lb,ub=ub,z=z,t1=0.25,t2=0.5,opts=list("algorithm" = "NLOPT_GN_DIRECT"))

> Unused arguments (z = c(-1.15, -0.32, 0.32, 1.15, -1.15, -0.32, 0.32, 1.15, -1.15, -0.32, 0.32, 1.15, -1.15, -0.32, 0.32, 1.15), t1 = 0.25, t2 = 0.5)
```

So there are basically three questions...

1. Does the nloptr make sense to solve this problem?
2. How can I pass further variables to my function that shall not be part of the optimization?
3. As you can see from my code above, I would like to optimize over a matrix. Is there any smarter way to do so or do I have to
   transform everything into a vector notation?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT 1:** The issue concerning the "unused arguments" can be solved by re-writing the constraint function.

```
f_constr_1 <- function(P,z,t1,t2){
    len <- sqrt(length(P))
    P <- matrix(P,len,len)
    f_constr_1 <- rowSums(P) - rep(1,ncol(P))
}
```

Comment: **SOLUTION:** Instead of nloptr() I used the solnp() from the Rsolnp package. Instead of passing a matrix I just convert it into an array and adjust the respective target and constraint functions accordingly. Not that nice but it works.
Last but not least, passing further variable works easily by passing a list containing the respective variables.

Comment: `resSOLNP <- solnp(pars   = c(P),
                            fun    = eval_f,
                            eqfun  = f_constr_1,
                            eqB    = rep(0,n),
                            LB     = rep(0,length(P)),
                            UB     = rep(1,length(P)),
                            L = list(z,t1,t2))`